# How Do you Display a Street Address using Searchkit?

Tags: search, search-results, searchkit

I am performing a search in searchkit and I want to display the primary address in the search results. I can easily add city state and zip, but I cant seem to add the street address fields. Instead a number is appearing. I am assuming I need to transform the number somehow, but unsure what to do. Typically in reports I would add street address and supplemental addresses, but that is not an option in searchkit.

Answer (score 1):

In dmaster I just checked in SearchKit and can see a field for  Address (Primary) Street Address.

Here currently but will flush in a few hours: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/edit/13

Comment: I see it now in demo master - but its not in my deployment of 5.58.1 (wordpress)

Comment: hmm - if you are happy to apply a patch you might want to ask (eg coleman) via https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/search-improvements where to find it